# Error in saving contents

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

i am able to login to drupal as admin but when ever i try to save any content or settings i get the error

```
The username admin does not exist
```

Comment: This is very strange. It seems like the drupal installation is somehow broken. Could you please check if the user id 1 exists in the database? (users table)

Comment: i do not have access to ftp and i cannot write simple php code to fetch from db as well because i cannot save a page/node also.I could only verify that admin username exists with all proper permissions.This was reported in drupal forums http://drupal.org/node/447288 and they gave this patch http://drupal.org/files/issues/content_profile_registration_1.patch but not sure how to use it ! plz help

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to a user related module altering the $user object. Your first and best bet is to make sure you are fully up to date with all your modules. If that doesn't solve it, you should disable modules one at a time until this error goes away. Any modules related to profiles or users should be suspect - content profile, etc.